# What is the proper way to install bubblewrap for opam (ideally without admin priviledges)?

Tags: ocaml, opam, bubblewrap

I am getting this error:

```
(iit_synthesis) brando9~ $ bash -c "sh <(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh)"
## Using already downloaded "/tmp/user/22003/opam-2.1.4-x86_64-linux"
## Where should it be installed ? [/lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.local/bin] ~/.local/bin
## '~/.local/bin' resolves to '/lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.local/bin', do you confirm [Y/n] Y
## opam 2.1.4 installed to /lfs/ampere4/0/brando9/.local/bin
## Converting the opam root format & updating
No configuration file found, using built-in defaults.
Checking for available remotes: rsync and local, git.
  - you won't be able to use mercurial repositories unless you install the hg command on your system.
  - you won't be able to use darcs repositories unless you install the darcs command on your system.

[WARNING] Missing dependencies -- the following commands are required for opam to operate:
  - bwrap: Sandboxing tool bwrap was not found. You should install 'bubblewrap'. See https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/FAQ.html#Why-does-opam-require-bwrap.
[ERROR] Sandboxing is not working on your platform ubuntu:
        "~/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build sh -c echo SUCCESS >$TMPDIR/opam-sandbox-check-out && cat $TMPDIR/opam-sandbox-check-out; rm -f
        $TMPDIR/opam-sandbox-check-out" exited with code 10
Do you want to disable it?  Note that this will result in less secure package builds, so please ensure that you have some other isolation mechanisms in
place (such as running within a container or virtual machine). [y/N]
```

but it doesn't link to a way to actually install it, link given https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/FAQ.html#Why-does-opam-require-bwrap and also I thought this would mean I don't need to do that:

```
opam init --disable-sandboxing
opam update --all
eval $(opam env)
```

am I wrong? I'm confused.

Answer (score 3):

To install `bubblewrap` on Ubuntu 18.04 or later just do

```
sudo apt-get install bubblewrap
```

If you have an older Ubuntu distribution or a distribution that doesn't package this program, then follow the instructions on the [bubblewrap](https://github.com/containers/bubblewrap) page to install it.

Of course, you can opt out of using `bubblewrap`, this is actually what the message is telling you. Just say, `y` for yes and it will continue without bubble-wrapping anything. For example, if you're building in a docker container, you don't need an extra layer of containerization that is provided by `bubblewrap` so you can drop it off.

> also I thought this would mean I don't need to do that:

```
opam init --disable-sandboxing
...
```

Yes, once you install `opam` the binary, and if you opted out of using `bubblewrap` you need to initialize opam with this option (opam installation roughly consists of two steps, first you download and install the binary, next you need to run `opam init` so that it configures itself in your system).